# What is the most efficient way to store URL's in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, space, varchar

This is not actually a coding question, but I want to learn something.

I'm trying to save picture URL's for items in the database. At first, I made the *img_url* column of type `TEXT`, but turns out it cannot have a default value, which I need.

So I guess I will use something like `VARCHAR(2000)` , but on the other hand, most of the items will have the value "local" which is varchar(5). So what I want to learn is, will the table use memory space as if all the rows have strings of 2000 characters, even though most of the cells contain 5-char strings?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the MySQL documentation on [Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html).

As you'll see, the cost of storing a value is not in the VARCHAR(length), but instead directly related to the data it is storing, with some overhead.

> VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)  L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255
>   bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes

The value `local`, thus would take 6 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

No.  That's what the `VAR` in `VARCHAR` indicates.

See [the documentation for VARCHAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html), especially the table about storage usage.